# Singleton instantiation

Tags: java, singleton

I have written the code shown below:

```
public class SiteMapFactory {

    public static ISiteMap getSiteMap(Locale loc) {
        ISiteMap returnMap = null;

        if (loc.equals(Locale.US)) {
            returnMap = SiteMap_en_US.getInstance();
        }
        if(loc.equals(new Locale("es","US"))){
            returnMap = SiteMap_en_US.getInstance();
        }
        if(loc.equals(Locale.CANADA)){
            returnMap = SiteMap_fr_CA.getInstance();
        }
        return returnMap;
    }
}
```

I want to return the same site map for both en_US (English) and es_US (Spanish) of our website. So I am instantiating the US sitemap for both Spanish and English version (a third party vendor is converting our English pages to Spanish). The way the site map is instantiated is using **singleton**. Singleton object is created as follows:

```
public class SiteMap_en_US extends SiteMapTree {
    private static SiteMap_en_US m_instance;

    private SiteMap_en_US() {}

    static {
        m_instance = new SiteMap_en_US();
        m_instance.init();
    }

    public static SiteMap_en_US getInstance(){
        return m_instance;
    }

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        //some code
    }
}
```

My question is: can I reuse the same singleton object twice? Is it a valid way of instantiating the singleton object?

Comment: You are not creating two instances, but returning same instance for both locale. So changes made in one locale will be reflected in object used in other locale which will be problematic.

Comment: That's what we want. As we only created the English templates. But a third party vendor is doing the Spanish translation and we did not deployed any of those template in our code base.  i was given a task to detect the Spanish site(i am doing it based on URL) and block certain things for Spanish. I can easily do that based on if/Else logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can reuse the same singleton object.

However:  If you do this, you should not have to include any special handling within the object to determine which language it is being used for, it should simply behave the same way all the time.

If you have to make it behave differently, consider creating a subclass of SiteMap_en_US (SiteMap_es_US perhaps) that is derived from SiteMap_en_US and has a small number of behaviors overridden.

It's possible to do all sorts of locale checks within the object to determine its behavior, but I highly recommend considering a different approach that's easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

This is why many agree that Singleton is an anti-pattern. You need multiple instances of the object, one for each locale. It's not a singleton. I like to say that Singleton is just a euphemism for global variables. You're basically allowing a global way to access the Locales.

[Singleton - The anti pattern](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/337)

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you say "you need 2 instances of the object".  Provided code only creates one instance.

Comment: @Wug: I want to reuse the same instance for both Spanish and English version. I want to know can i do that by coding like above

Comment: @Wug I mean that OP has an instance for each locale. It may be separate classes so you only have a single instance of each class. However, to me, it's still creating a number of global `SiteMapTree`s (accessible through singletons)

Comment: @pushya: You can provided the two are to behave exactly the same.  Otherwise, you might be better off using a subclass of `SiteMap_en_US` (`SiteMap_es_US` perhaps?) which overrides a specific portion of the functionality.  My comment was directed at the author of this answer who made a claim which is false.

Comment: @Wug: I have edited my question. Actually i want to know can i reuse the singleton object shown above

Comment: Can you convert the singleton objects into enums? If they are stateless, as they should be, this should be a drop-in. It's easy to override methods for particular values of an enum, very handy, very good way of _fixing_ Singleton anti-pattern in the absence of state data.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I do agree that the case where singletons don't cause trouble is when they don't manage any state (global variables are OK in that case also). I like your comparison to Enums. At a previous company, we used this same kind of technique (that OP is using) and we called it "multiton" That's when we started realizing that something was not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

You can create base `class SiteMapUS` and extend it to create two subclasses `SiteMapUSEnglish` and `SiteMapUSSpanish`.

```
public class SiteMapUS{
    protected SiteMapUS(){

    }
}

public class SiteMapUSEnglish{

    protected SiteMapUSEnglish(){

    }

    public SiteMapUSEnglish getInstance(){
        //return instance
    }

}


public class SiteMapUSSpanish{

    protected SiteMapUSSpanish(){

    }

    public SiteMapUSSpanish getInstance(){
        //return instance
    }

}
```

place all classes in separate package.

This is the simplest way to achieve your goal. Benefit of using this approach is that you can easily modify/add locale related changes without modifying other code.